# Java int issue while intializtion

Tags: java, int

I have been working on a project and i saw some references on web and they initialized :

```
int val= 0x000; output 0
int val1= 0x001; output 1
```

How exactly java is converting this?

Thanks

Comment: what do you mean by converting? `0x` prefix simply means 16-base integer

Comment: Did you read http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html ?  Particularly the section on integer literals.  It talks about hexadecimal.

Comment: I don't see any issues here.....

Answer (score 4):

It's an **hexadecimal** (base 16 instead of base 10). Hexadecimals starts with `0x...`. And it can contain these digits: `0123456789ABCDEF`

**Octals** (base 8) starts with `0...` and can containt digits less than 8 (`01234567`)

```
int dec = 123; // decimal: 1*(10^2) + 2*(10^1) + 3*(10^0) = 123
int oct = 0123; // octal: 1*(8^2) + 2*(8^1) + 3*(8^0) = 83
int hex = 0x123; // hexadecimal: 1*(16^2) + 2*(16^1) + 3*(16^0) = 291
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do `int val = 0;` and `int val = 1;`  with decimal notation..

The `0x` before the number indicate an hexadecimal notation...

All notations are:

**0b** to **binary**: `int i = 0b10101010110;`

**nothing** to **decimal**: `int i = 123;`

**0** to **octal**: `int i = 0123345670;`

**0x** to **hexadecimal**: `int i = 0xAEF123`;

Comment: `0b` is only support in Java 7 and later

Answer (score 0):

As a matter of fact, Java does not "convert" but "interpret" the values (as hexadecimal).

Answer (score 0):

Numbers starting with 0x are hexadecimal. Java converts them (like decimal ones, too) to binary and saves them.

Answer (score 0):

This **hexadecimal** number system (base 16)

Start with 0x...

(**Octals** start with 0...)

[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10920432/why-use-hexadecimal-constants/10920553#10920553)

Comment: Sorry, I copied a PDF