# C# AuthenticationTypes?

Tags: c#, authentication, active-directory

I came across the following line in a piece of code that uses Microsoft Active Directory:

```
const AuthenticationTypes ADS_EDMSERVER_BIND = (AuthenticationTypes)0x8000;
```

What exactly does this line mean ? Particularly, what is the `0x8000` mean ?

Comment: `0x8000` is probably hex for `32768`

Comment: @NikolaiSamteladze If it is 32768, what is its purpose in this case ?

Comment: You mean what is the purpose of using hexadecimal instead of an integer?

Comment: Yes. And in addition, what does the number specify ?

Comment: Please see my answer. The number just specifies some `AuthenticationTypes` value or may be used as a mask in bit operations (e.g. `|` or `&`). Need to see how `AuthenticationTypes` enumeration looks and how `ADS_EDMSERVER_BIND` to provide more details.

Answer (score 0):

`0x8000` is just a hexadecimal representation of integer `32768`. So this line of code essentially defines a constant of enumerable type `AuthenticationTypes` with a value of `32768`. The number just specifies some AuthenticationTypes value or may be used as a mask in bit operations (e.g. | or &).

Hexadecimal representations are sometimes used to improve readability or show relations to binary values (there is a nice discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10920432/why-use-hexadecimal-constants)). The simplest example is constants that are used in masks or with bit operators.